# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sktime.utils.data_io'

Tags: python-3.9, sktime

I have already installed sktime using this command `pip3.9 install sktime`. However still getting error on importing `from sktime.utils.data_io import load_from_tsfile_to_dataframe`. Here is the error:

```
from sktime.utils.data_io import load_from_tsfile_to_dataframe
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sktime.utils.data_io'
```

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this problem by replacing:

```
import sktime
from sktime.datasets import load_from_tsfile_to_dataframe
```

It seems that the new version of sktime is introduced with new syntax

Comment: Same as `load_from_arff_to_dataframe`